# Increment address in cout expression renders unexpected output

Tags: c++, cout

I don't understand what is happening here. There must be something related to "flush" termen but I would like an explanation.

```
int arr[4] {3,8,1,6};

cout<<arr[0];
cout<<arr[1];
cout<<arr[2];
cout<<arr[3];

cout<<endl;

cout<<&arr[0]<<endl;
cout<<&arr[1]<<'\n';
cout<<&arr[2]<<endl;
cout<<&arr[3]<<endl;

cout<<&arr[0]<<endl;

int *j = &arr[0];
cout << *j << *(++j) << *(++j) << *(++j); // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
```

Why this last `cout` instruction tends to output the numbers reversed?
It seems to me like backtracking but I'm not sure.

I was expecting `3816` as output, instead I got `6618`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the expression

```
cout << *j << *(++j) << *(++j) << *(++j);
```

The [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) is not well defined, so the [behaviour is undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

> Examples of undefined behavior are memory accesses outside of array bounds, signed integer overflow, null pointer dereference, **more than one modifications of the same scalar in an expression without any intermediate sequence point (until C++11) that are unsequenced (since C++11)**

I [ran it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Wo95NGhEKPiq2u0u) and it outputed `3816`. Note that with warning flags this is detected by the compiler.

If you try:

```
cout << *j;
cout << *(++j);
cout << *(++j); 
cout << *(++j);
```

This well sequenced expression will render the expected output.